# Modification of jQuery Gridly plugin

Tags: html, css

[Here](http://ksylvest.github.io/jquery-gridly/)'s the link to Gridly.

As you can see, when we click on a box, it expands. Now, what I need is, that when the box expands, it reveals something.

What exactly I'll be doing is that I'll be putting an image covering the box when it is small. And when it expands, some text will get revealed along with the image. [Here](http://www.inktalks.com/conferences/ink2013/program/speakers)'s an example. It's somewhat similar to this. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about: http://jsfiddle.net/wp2E4/

The code as a single page:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://codeorigin.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.gridly.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="jquery.gridly.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<style type="text/css">
  .gridly {
    position: relative;
    width: 960px;
  }
  .brick {
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  .brick img {
    padding: 10px;
  }
  .brick div {
    padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
  }
  .brick.small {
    width: 140px;
    height: 140px;
    background-color: gray;
  }
  .brick.large {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: #B0B0B0;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="gridly">
  <div class="brick small"><img src="http://placehold.it/120x120" /><div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. Praesent mauris. Fusce nec tellus sed augue semper porta. Mauris massa. Vestibulum lacinia arcu eget nulla.</div></div>
  <div class="brick small"><img src="http://placehold.it/120x120" /><div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. Praesent mauris. Fusce nec tellus sed augue semper porta. Mauris massa. Vestibulum lacinia arcu eget nulla.</div></div>
  <div class="brick large"><img src="http://placehold.it/120x120" /><div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. Praesent mauris. Fusce nec tellus sed augue semper porta. Mauris massa. Vestibulum lacinia arcu eget nulla.</div></div>
  <div class="brick small"><img src="http://placehold.it/120x120" /><div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. Praesent mauris. Fusce nec tellus sed augue semper porta. Mauris massa. Vestibulum lacinia arcu eget nulla.</div></div>
  <div class="brick small"><img src="http://placehold.it/120x120" /><div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. Praesent mauris. Fusce nec tellus sed augue semper porta. Mauris massa. Vestibulum lacinia arcu eget nulla.</div></div>
  <div class="brick small"><img src="http://placehold.it/120x120" /><div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. Praesent mauris. Fusce nec tellus sed augue semper porta. Mauris massa. Vestibulum lacinia arcu eget nulla.</div></div>
  <div class="brick small"><img src="http://placehold.it/120x120" /><div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. Praesent mauris. Fusce nec tellus sed augue semper porta. Mauris massa. Vestibulum lacinia arcu eget nulla.</div></div>
  <div class="brick small"><img src="http://placehold.it/120x120" /><div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. Praesent mauris. Fusce nec tellus sed augue semper porta. Mauris massa. Vestibulum lacinia arcu eget nulla.</div></div>
  <div class="brick small"><img src="http://placehold.it/120x120" /><div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. Praesent mauris. Fusce nec tellus sed augue semper porta. Mauris massa. Vestibulum lacinia arcu eget nulla.</div></div>
  <div class="brick large"><img src="http://placehold.it/120x120" /><div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. Praesent mauris. Fusce nec tellus sed augue semper porta. Mauris massa. Vestibulum lacinia arcu eget nulla.</div></div>
  <div class="brick small"><img src="http://placehold.it/120x120" /><div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. Praesent mauris. Fusce nec tellus sed augue semper porta. Mauris massa. Vestibulum lacinia arcu eget nulla.</div></div>
  <div class="brick small"><img src="http://placehold.it/120x120" /><div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. Praesent mauris. Fusce nec tellus sed augue semper porta. Mauris massa. Vestibulum lacinia arcu eget nulla.</div></div>
  <div class="brick small"><img src="http://placehold.it/120x120" /><div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. Praesent mauris. Fusce nec tellus sed augue semper porta. Mauris massa. Vestibulum lacinia arcu eget nulla.</div></div>
</div>
<script>
  $('.gridly').gridly({
    base: 60, // px 
    gutter: 20, // px
    columns: 12
  });
  $('.brick').click(function() {
    $this = $(this);

    // toggle the size of the brick using css class
    $this.toggleClass('large').toggleClass('small');

    // this is set to ensure the layout is carried out on the final size of the brick
    size = $this.hasClass('small') ? 140 : 300;
    $this.data('width', size);
    $this.data('height', size);

    return $('.gridly').gridly('layout');
  });

</script>
</body>
```

The javascript is taken from the sample on github: https://github.com/ksylvest/jquery-gridly/blob/master/javascripts/sample.js. The text 'flows' a little as the brick resizes, a fixed size text div would stop this.

Nice plugin btw, gridly takes care of nearly all the pain of the animation for you, both colour and size are interpolated automagically.

Comment: Awesome! Exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

While you tagged this question as javascript and jquery, this seems to be a CSS problem to me. Look at the DOM when you click a box. You can see it toggles the `small` and `large` class. If you want to change how certain things look when you click the box, you define the css for both that element in a `small` brick and in a `large` brick.

Without knowing what you actually want, I can't suggest much. An example for an image that get's bigger when the brick is clicked is:

```
<div class="brick small">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/300/300" />
</div>
```

with css:

```
.brick.small img {
  width: 140px;
  height: 140px;
}

.brick.large img {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
```